# Getting data from several database table as an array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

[My Database Look Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koyYZ.png)

I want to get all column1's data that has "asde" in its column2 and use them to create a dropdown list. How can i do that?

I used this

```
    $deneme = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2 LIKE '%INSE%'";
    $deneme2 = mysql_query($deneme);
    $deneme3 = mysql_fetch_array($deneme2);
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? The query? Putting them into an array, or creating a dropdown list from the array? Please show what you've written so far so we can help you fix it. We're not here to write your whole script for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
$q = mysql_query("select column1, column2 from table where column2 LIKE '%asde%'");
```

Then use it for dropDownList options:

```
echo '<select name="fhdfh">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_NUM))
    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'" selected>'.$row[1].'</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to select them with for loop. I selected but when i try to echo them out i can't.

Comment: @user3552536 give us example of code that doesn't work

Comment: I deleted it because it didn't work. But i wrote similar to one that i used.

Comment: It says 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  on line 40 | 
Line 40-> $data = mysql_fetch_array($q);

Comment: Thanks a lot!. But there is one thing that i want to do. It's not that important like the one before. What if i want to do this for all 114 table. $q will be array. What about $row. Is will be like kind of multidimensional array?

Comment: @Zeki you can't get multidimensional array from mysql. You should fetch results for each table in loop and put them in other array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select distinct column1  from table where column2 = 'asde'